# If I buy GTA V with a key via social club, can I then add the game to steam?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

I read that you can't associate a retail copy of GTA V to Steam. But I also see on several places that if you buy GTA from Steam that you may also need a social club account.

Now, currently there is no discount on Steam if I want to buy GTA V, So I'll have to pay 59€. But I can buy a key for GTA V via social club online for only 29€.

Is it possible to link GTA V from social club to Steam?

Comment: Where's the deal I can't seam to find anything anywhere on the socialclub site ?

Comment: No, sorry for the misunderstanding... What I mean to say is that You can buy a key online from a third party and you can use this key on social club....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While you can add the GTAV.exe file as a non-steam game shortcut, it will just be a shortcut.
To get the proper steam version, you will have to buy it either from Steam, or buy a Steam key from a third party reseller (most, however, don't sell steam keys for GTA V).

If you buy the Steam version, you can also play it as the social club version without running steam, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, that's what I wanted to know. Any additional benefits on waiting till it's on sale on steam? (I read that I should be able to download the game via social club in the future as well, should my computer crash)

Comment: @user1841243 I have GTA V as a RSSC download. I find that their servers are slower to download patches from. Apart from that, the Steam version requires you to register a RSSC account regardless because GTA Online runs on their servers, so even if you don't want to use the steam client for whatever reason, you can still download it from there. Note that you can only have 1 GTA V license on one RSSC account,although I'm not sure if you can buy the game on Steam, then use another already linked license.

Comment: Steam version has generally better download servers, but I think the main difference is that it's easier to manage your games if they're all in one library and you get achievements on Steam. If it's worth paying extra for those features is for you to decide. (I did)